# Question over Json sorting

Tags: javascript

> http://www.devcurry.com/2010/05/sorting-json-array.html

I came across this article, i want few explantions over this article.

```
    function SortByName(x,y) {      
        return ((x.Name == y.Name) ? 0 : ((x.Name > y.Name) ? 1 : -1 ));   
    }

arr.sort(SortByName);
```

1. What would be the arguements for arr.sort(x,y). What will be passed to the function from the JSON Object.
2. What does the SortByName function return. I don't understand the entire line. can anyone give me more details over this.

Comment: Although the article claims so, there is no JSON in this code. Just an array of JavaScript objects. See also http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would be the arguements for arr.sort(x,y).

The two values in the array that are currently being compared

> What does the SortByName function return

0, -1 or 1 depending on which of the two Name properties was bigger.

You should probably read the [documentation for sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Answer (score 1):

The argument of [sort](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) is a function that will be called several times with two different elements of the array, and will return 0 if the elements are equal, 1 if  x > y and -1 if y > x.

```
return ((x.Name == y.Name) ? 0 : ((x.Name > y.Name) ? 1 : -1 ));
```

is the very same as:

```
if (x.Name == y.Name) 
   return 0;
else
   if (x.Name > y.Name) 
      return 1;
   else
      return -1;
```